# MySqlDataReader doesn't return a value

Tags: c#

so, I have this code

```
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306; Database=brez-db;Uid=root;Pwd=root;");

        try {
            connection.Open();
            String Query = "SELECT 1 FROM users_table WHERE user_Username='" + usernameTB.Text + "' AND user_Password='" + passwordTB.Password + "'";
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                String str = myReader.GetString("user_Username").ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(str);
            }


        }
        catch(Exception ex) { throw; }
        finally { }
```

but

```
while(myReader.Read()){}
```

returns only 1 and 0 . 1 if there is a value inside and 0 if there's nothing.

I've tried many things to get the value but nothing, any suggestion?
I'm writing a wpf C# app

PS: I know that its a good thing to use parameters for security, but I want to make a simple code for now

Comment: you do "SELECT 1" and then expect user_Username column to be present. It won't be!

Comment: [Happy Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: And also, it is funny that you try to read the username that you already have in the TextBox text.

Comment: @MitchWheat can you please explain better?

Comment: @Steve I know, but I will need this function other times and don't want to wait till later.

Comment: @MitchWheat you are right, I shouldnt be using SELECT 1 there, because it would turn the myReader to bool.

Comment: Did you mean `SELECT TOP 1` instead to get a single row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove 1 after the select. Also you should use query for the name of your string,not Query,it looks like it is reserved for something.
Also,you should get your string like this:

```
string sUsername= myReader["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

or like this

```
string sUsername= myReader[0].ToString();
```

And in the finally you are missing `connection.Close();`